# Subtracting a string to a Object Value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, object, null, subtraction

was wondering How I can subtract a string to a Input Object Value using jQuery.

Ex.

```
console.log($("#freqmain").val() + $("#freqmain2").val() + " Hz");       freqmain3 = 150 Hz
```

Now if I want to take out the "Hz" string I guessed I have to use "-" instead of "+" but this is giving me a NaN result;

```
console.log($("#freqmain3").val() - " Hz");       = NaN (instead of = 150)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Which is the best approach to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var val = $("#freqmain").val() + " Hz"
var new_nal = val.replace(/(Hz)/, '');
console.log(new_nal);
```